# `finalName` parameter not allowed in maven-jar-plugin configuration

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-jar-plugin

We have recently tried to upgrade our `maven-jar-plugin` from `2.3.2` version to `3.0.2`. Since the change we were using the plugin as follows -

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.2</version>
     <configuration>
          <finalName>mobile-test-suite</finalName>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But changing the version to the latest reads -

> Element finalName is not allowed here

***Has the usage changed or deprecated? Is there a way I can still give a final name to my jar?***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<finalName>` goes directly under `<project>/<build>`, not under `maven-jar-plugin`.

You can read more about it in the comments section of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-233